# Function System() using Octave

Tags: shell, alias, octave

I have done a shortcut to open LTSpice simulator on terminal, to open the program typing "ltspice", I used the alias command and the path of the program and saved to bashrc.

It's working pretty good on terminal, but when I try to use the command on octave:

```
    system('ltspice');
```

it returns,

```
    sh: 1: ltspice: not found
```

Answer (score 2):

Aliases are only available in the session that defined them (as they are meant for interactive use) so Octave will not see them.

I'd recommend that you instead specify the full path to `ltspice` in the call to `system()`.

Answer (score 0):

Aliases are meant for interactive shells. Bash only reads `.bashrc` when it starts an interactive shell. There is no configuration file¹ that makes aliases available to the `system` function. Such a feature could be dangerous² because it would affect every single shell command invoked by an application, and possibly make it do something unexpected.

To make an application available from anywhere, make sure that the directory where the executable is in your [command search path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)). Either add the directory to your path in your login scripts, e.g.

```
PATH="$PATH:/opt/ltspice/bin"
```

or put a symbolic link to the executable in a directory that's already on your path, e.g.

```
ln -s /opt/ltspice/bin/ltspice /usr/local/bin/ltsipce
```

¹  <sub>Actually there is — all common `sh` shells read the file designated by the `ENV` environment variable. But I don't recommend using this anyway.</sub> 
²  <sub>It is. Csh users get bitten by their `.cshrc` from time to time. There's a reason why csh scripts tend to start with `/bin/csh -f`.</sub>